# How to Open my GIT REPO in VS CODE in Linux

Tags: linux, git, visual-studio-code

I have installed the VS Code by following the VS CODE site.
Now I want to use it to open my git repository to edit files.
Installation is completed on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clone your repo first to a local directory.
2. Open VSCode.
3. Select 'File-->Open Folder' and select the cloned folder.

The files will be shown in the side bar.

Comment: I need to open in Linux, my clone repo is in /home

Comment: @SohaniSharma Start vscode on your linux machine, open the folder that contains your cloned repo in vscode, just like Jeril says

Comment: from CLI, (as VSCode should be in the PATH), you could also enter `code .`